# Can't fade UIToolbar or UITabbar in iOS7

Tags: uikit, core-animation, ios7, uitabbar, uitoolbar

I set up a new application with a tab bar at the bottom. Below is the `viewDidAppear:` method of my root view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 0.0f;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:10.0f delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState animations:^{
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.tabBarController.tabBar.alpha = 1.0f;
    } completion:nil];
}
```

What I observe is that as soon as the view appears, it has `alpha = 1.0f`. I'd expect it to start out with `alpha = 0.0f` and then fade to have `alpha = 1.0f`. The background, on the other hand, fades to have `backgroundColor` red as expected.

The same thing happens when I try to fade a `UIToolbar`.

Answer (score 5):

Set allowsGroupOpacity of the UIToolbar's parent view layer to NO. Add a check since it is new in iOS 7. Preferably in viewDidLoad:

```
if([self.view.layer respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsGroupOpacity:)]) {
    self.view.layer.allowsGroupOpacity = NO;
}
```